# Slicing for web page, containing rounded images that overlap other parts

Tags: html, css

I have a psd file with layers that is a mockup of a web page I need to create. You can view a page scheme [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02656093429916582867). For each page element (header, menu, main body, footer, etc) there are layers in the psd file. There are also some rounded images with drop-shadow that also constitute layers and they overlap among themselves, as well as the main body text area and the header of the page, as you can see in the page scheme.

My question is, what would be the correct method to export slices for using the exported images in the page markup:

Option 1: Export the rounded images as layer-based slices (after I turn off any other layers below them) and use transperency attributes for the images.

Option 2: Export rectangular user-slices that contain a page part (eg, main body) and the parts of the rounded images that overlap this page part.

For example, in the 1st case, I would export all 3 rounded images as a layer-based .png slice (after I turned off the header and main-body layers), ending up with the 3 images with transparency. Then I would place this image with absolute positioning, so it overlaps the main-body and header.

In the 2nd case, I would slice the whole header part with the part of the img1 that overlaps it, then I would slice the menu, then I would slice the main body part, including the parts of the images that overlap it, then I would cut another slice to the right, containing the rest of the images' parts and so on. If you go to this [link](https://wordpress.org/themes/travelogue) and click on the template thumbnail, you could check with Firebug a similar approach to the 2nd option, regarding the floating images on the upper left of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is the way to go. With option 2, a design change or repositioning of the circles requires you to re-slice everything again.